# RPC call gettransaction does not work on bitcoin 0.10.2

Tags: json-rpc

Hello I have upgraded my bitcoind to 0.10.2, some of my rpc request now doesn't work.
This is an example:
bitcoin-cli gettransaction 6f5dfa31bef79d0c8cdd58530fc9f0ed2427e7085d421755f3fe78c
a6ac326ef
error: {"code":-5,"message":"Invalid or non-wallet transaction id"}

i have in bitcoin.conf 
txindex=1
reindex=1

any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

If the transaction is not in your wallet, the RPC call you want to be using is `getrawtransaction` not `gettransaction`.

```
$ bitcoin-cli getrawtransaction 6f5dfa31bef79d0c8cdd58530fc9f0ed2427e7085d421755f3fe78ca6ac326ef 1
{
  "hex": "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",
  "txid": "6f5dfa31bef79d0c8cdd58530fc9f0ed2427e7085d421755f3fe78ca6ac326ef",
  "version": 1,
  "locktime": 0,
  "vin": [
    {
      "txid": "c88f369cfe24e402eafd97c7318183ed780baa3b92a3459fc161eb9472ea532b",
      "vout": 1,
      "scriptSig": {
        "asm": "3045022100acc3143388da78db06726c89f5c05a2e25560e6df27ff0df1918f6e1f12629b202205ab9ae4b639742450f64e2014eadd6433d269f0d37a3c3fdad2b19076e546ab701 034a506701c7698e39a20f3de3f81b76c623ee7530ccac43465ea69f73c6fbe444",
        "hex": "483045022100acc3143388da78db06726c89f5c05a2e25560e6df27ff0df1918f6e1f12629b202205ab9ae4b639742450f64e2014eadd6433d269f0d37a3c3fdad2b19076e546ab70121034a506701c7698e39a20f3de3f81b76c623ee7530ccac43465ea69f73c6fbe444"
      },
[....]
```